# Playing a video without stopping (Swift)

Tags: swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play 10-20 second videos on my swift App but sometimes because of slow internet it stops and doesn't load again until I pause it and play. So what I want to do is before streaming, download the full video so it doesn't stop in middle again. This is the code I'm using

```
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
        moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.None;
        moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = false
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = false
        moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        moviePlayer.view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did, added an observer to find if downloading

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "videoStopped:", name: MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification, object: moviePlayer)
```

handle the playing in **videoStopped Function** using **moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime and moviePlayer.playableDuration**

Comment: can you give me code for this. I am facing same issue for streaming movies inside app. My video pauses when slow internet, how to handle.

Comment: func videoStopped(notication:NSNotification) { *play it again here* }